# PySpark remove the need for loop

Tags: loops

I am fairly new to PySpark and need to work out how to use PySpark correctly and remove the need for this loop which is taking hours to run. I am looping through customer records dataframe then checking to see if an Engineer is available in customers area in the Engineer Dataframe. If there is an Engineer available I do JOBS_LEFT-1 in the Engineer Dataframe. I also mark the customer as having an Engineer assigned.

Appreciate any help

Thanks

```
engAvail=spark.sql("SELECT EMPLOYEE_NO,concat('#',SECTOR,',') as SECTOR,JOBS_LEFT from tmpEmployeeAvailability WHERE JOBS_LEFT >0 ORDER BY  JOBS_LEFT desc")

for index,rows in df_priority_customer.iterrows():

    engAvail = engAvail.filter(col("JOBS_LEFT")>0)

    pd = "#" + df_priority_customer.loc[index,'POSTAL_DISTRICT'] + ","
   
    empNo= engAvail.filter(col("SECTOR").contains(pd))
        
    if (empNo.count() > 0) :        
        #print(empNo.count())
        #print(empNo.collect()[0][0]) #First Row
        engAvail = engAvail.withColumn('JOBS_LEFT', when(engAvail.EMPLOYEE_NO == int(empNo.collect()[0][0]), engAvail.JOBS_LEFT-1).otherwise(engAvail.JOBS_LEFT))        
        df_priority_customer.at[index,'ASSIGNED_ENGINEER'] = 'Y'
    else:
        #print('No Engineer')
        df_priority_customer.at[index,'ASSIGNED_ENGINEER'] = 'N'
```

Comment: Hi @GaryH75, the design here is definitely a bottleneck because collects are very expensive. You also have this Spark DataFrame that keeps mutating. I think what you can do is partition your data by either SECTOR or POSTAL_DISTRICT. I am hoping each engineer only belongs in one SECTOR or POSTAL_DISTRICT. After that, we can partition the engineers table in the same way. For each partition, treat the logic as a Pandas DataFrame and loop over Pandas instead. It will be much faster than Spark. I can help with this (contact info in profile). I can't write a full solution without sample data.

Comment: The ideal scenario here is if you can perform a clever join of-course to bypass the step-wise assignment. I am honestly not seeing it though.